# Who knows the Doctor's name?

Tags: doctor-who

Who, apart from from River Song knows the Doctor's true name? In The Time of the Doctor, the time lords want him to say his name to prove they have the right universe and it is safe to come through - would the doctor's name have been common knowledge amongst time lords, or was it a specific set of time lords asking?

I was under the impression the doctor's name was secret even from most Galifreyans - am I mistaken?

Comment: Well, the High Council would be one I guess - otherwise they wouldn't be making the question.

Comment: We never know for sure that River actually does know his name. Rule #1. The Doctor lies. And the corollary, River lies.

Comment: @BBlake the the password for tardis tomb is fake too

Comment: Damn, you asked exactly the question I wanted to ask at just about the time I came up with the idea of asking it! Are you _me_?

Comment: Clara knows it in an alternative dead timeline and there is nothing bad happening to her due to that reason.

Answer (score 5):

[The Matrix](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Matrix) would have contained The Doctor's name; however, access to The Matrix was at least somewhat limited. Given that the revelation of a Time Lord's name is a sacrament of marriage, one might assume that casual attempts to access such data are discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in one episode – might be last one of Season 4 (if i am right) – where Donna becomes a Time Lord, she says she got the Doctor's mind. This seems to imply, since she got the Doctor's mind, that she would know the Doctor's name.